# Having objects trajectories and directions. How to find where objects traverse same path?

Tags: search

I have `N` objects that travel on some trajectories inside some box. (unique for each object). At each agent curve point we can get object speed (direction). Having some distance creteria `d` how to find where more than one curve go in same direction cloze to each other with distance `<= d`. How to find such curves? (question is aboun `M` dimesional space, each point of each given trajectory can participate only in one such curve at a time, given trajectories do intersect)

alike having black object trajectory curves we find red curve that with some `d` follows most curves direction:

[image]

Comment: While an interesting question, this seems like more of a math problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well I need to implement it so for me its more algorithmical than  mathmetical... And I need algorithm to work fast..(

Comment: I see three distinct steps here: 1) Figure out the math 2) Write the algorithm 3) Optimize the algorithm for speed. Have you done step 1 yet?

Comment: @RQDQ nope havent done it yet